# How to use youtube onPlay={} function with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I installed youtube-react API and you I got the onPlay function to work but the issue was it was very slow to load videos `<YouTube videoId={Projects.videoID}  onPlay={autoplayChange} onPause={autoplayChange} onEnd={autoplayChange}/>`

How can I recreate this similar function using a regular iframe with the youtube API? I can't find any documentation about implementing this into reactjs. https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference googles API reference mentions the functions under onStateChange but I cant figure out the implementation I thought someone on here might have an answer to my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `react-player`, you can install it quickly with npm:

```
npm install react-player
```

It is fast and will give you a lot of control over the onPlay functionality that you are looking for. Example from the [git](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player):

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player/lazy'

// Lazy load the YouTube player
<ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' />
```

With hooks you can add onPlay functionality like so:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player/lazy'

const MyPlayer = () => {

    const [ playState, setPlayState ] = useState(false);

    const yourFunction = (event) => {

        console.log('Your event: ', event);

    };

    return (
        <ReactPlayer 
            url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U'
            playing={playState}
            onPlay={yourFunction}/>
    );

}
```

Comment: Thanks man will give it a go I think from memory I tried to use this before but experienced lots of issues with DOM errors in the console and it scared me lol, will report back on if it works though

Comment: @lukeet I am happy to help you through those errors if they arise, simply open a new question and ping me and I'll walk you though how to solve those pesky warnings!

Comment: Thank you so much the help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: sorry man Idk how to ping/tag you but I was right this is the error I get Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('<URL>') does not match the recipient window's origin ('<URL>').

Comment: @lukeet no worries, I'll watch your profile for the next few mins. Want to open a new question? I know the reason for that and can provide some context.

Comment: Ok thanks will open the question now, could be too soon to posting this mind you if it is I'll post it in an edit in the form of an update